# How do we request a one-word invocation name for our Google Action?

Tags: actions-on-google

We previously used the link at

https://developers.google.com/assistant/support/?requesttype=appnamewhitelist

as documented in [this article](https://developers.google.com/assistant/console/policies/general-policies#name_requirements) to fill in a support ticket but this link now redirects to stack overflow, reddit or github.  Please can you help.

Answer (score 2):

The support form has been moved to https://support.google.com/actions-console/contact/support

Visit that page and use the category **Invocation Name assistance** in the dropdown.